# $a \equiv b\pmod m \iff a \bmod m = b \bmod m$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$a \equiv b\pmod m \iff a \bmod m = b \bmod m$

**My attempt:**

$$a \equiv \pmod m \Leftarrow a \pmod m = b \pmod m$$

$$\exists q_1, q_2\in\mathbb{R} \mid (a = mq_1 + r) \wedge (b = mq_2 + r)$$

Hence,

$$(a = mq_1 + r) - (b = mq_2 + r) = ((a-b) = m(q_1-q_2))$$

Thus, $m\mid(a-b)$

Therefore, $a \equiv b \pmod m$

**My problem is the converse**

$$a \equiv b\pmod m \Rightarrow a \bmod m = b \bmod m$$

$$(b-a) = md_1$$

From here I don't know how to show: $a \bmod m = b \bmod m$

I know that by definition, $a \equiv b(\bmod m)$ means that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder, should I just quote that? I simply don't know how to formalize it.

Comment: How are you defining the function $a \mod m$?

Comment: @vadim123 $a \bmod m$ formally is $a = d*m + r$ where $r = 0$ or $m|a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To finish up your proof of the converse: $$b-a= md_1\\\implies b-md_2-(a\pmod{m})=md_1\\\implies b=m (d_1+d_2)+(a\pmod{m})\\\implies b\pmod{m}=m (d_1+d_2)+(a\pmod{m})\pmod{m}\\\implies b\pmod{m}=a\pmod{m}$$

Note that here $d_1$ and $d_2$ are integers defined by $d_1=\dfrac{b-a}{m}$ and $d_2=\left\lfloor\dfrac{a}{m}\right\rfloor$.